# s3 deleteObj success return empty object

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
s3Bucket.deleteObject({
                Bucket: 'assets.memori.my',
                Key: key
                }, function(err,data){
                  console.log(data);
                  res.end();
  })
```

I checked my file did got deleted but what I get in data is an {}, where does the success callback come?

Comment: What do you mean by *"where does the success callback come"* ? What do you expect instead of an empty object?

Comment: @FelixKling some sort of positive response, empty object means success? that's bad api design, or I used it wrongly?

Comment: I don't know. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: yes http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property

Comment: Is there anything in `err`?  You don't appear to be checking it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot no err.

Answer (score 1):

That is expected.

Per the documentation, `data` can contain the following params:

- `DeleteMarker`
- `VersionId`
- `RequestCharged`

The first two are relevant only for versioned objects, the 3rd only if the requester doesn't own the bucket. It looks like none of these cases are applicable to you.

How do you know if your request was successful? Per the documentation, your request was successful if `err` is `null`. For failed requests, `data` would be `null`.

> **err** (Error) — the error object returned from the request. Set to `null` if the request is successful.
>   **data** (Object) — Set to `null` if a request error occurs.

Comment: empty object means success? what a bad design

Comment: well, i didn't design the API. I just answered your question

Comment: In my case it throws error only when wrong bucket is provided. On successful deletion both err and data are returning null. Any ideas ?